# Running a bash script to append .csv to files in a subdirectory moved/delted all files from computer

Tags: bash, scripting

I had a folder with 100 subfolders, and in each folder contained two files that I wanted to add .csv to. I wrote a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in * ; do     
    cd $i   
    for k in *; do      
        mv "$k" "${f%.*}.csv"
    done
    cd .. 
done
```

Where did all of my files go? How do I get them back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mv "$k" "${f%.*}.csv"
```

Since the `f` variable is not defined, the whole substitution amounts no an empty string, and the command becomes `mv "$k" ".csv"`.

All but one file in each directory has been lost. The last one is now named `.csv`. You probably didn't notice it because the dot in the beginning makes the file hidden; use `ls -a` to see such files. GUI file managers usually have an option to show hidden files, too.

Comment: All but one file in each directory has been deleted for good? This script left the directory I was originally in and went to every possible directory on my computer. Never mind I found everything in a folder named .csv